# Umbraco 7: change sort order for Blog Overview in Starter Kit

Tags: jquery, linq, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7 on our guinea pigs' website. The blog overview page is sorting the oldest first and you have to scroll down to get newer ones, which is not what I (or anyone for that matter) want.
Code is:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}

<div role="content">

<section class="light blogarchive equalizer">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            @foreach(var post in CurrentPage.Children) 
            {
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="content equal">
                        <a href="@post.Url">
                            <div class="date">@post.CreateDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
                            <h2>@post.Name</h2>     
                            <p>@Umbraco.Truncate(post.Introduction, 240, true)</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</div>
```

But I know Umbraco has their own flavor of everything under the sun .NET in their code so, I had tried LINQing in there to no avail.

I bet it's something so simple. I just want to sort by the CreatedDate or PublishDate (not sure what's available) descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it:

```
@foreach(var post in CurrentPage.Children.OrderBy("CreateDate desc"))
```

Like I said, Umbraco has it's own flavor of everything, even LINQ-ish...

Comment: Also, if you use IPublishedContent instead of dynamics you can use regular linq. Instead of CurrentPage, use Model.Content. This will give you the more strongly typed version of the current page. Then you can do things like Model.Content.Children.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateDate)